# Can Sqlplus read the contents of a file into a variable?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I've been tinkering with sqlplus for awhile now, and I've managed to get sqlplus to read the contents of a file into a substitution variable as such:

```
exit | sqlplus -s login/pass@db @script.sql "`cat file.txt`"
```

This mostly works as my script requires... even newlines in the file are preserved. However, I was only using a sample file which was 50 or 60 bytes in size. The actual files I'll end up using will be at least a few kilobytes. So it was at this point I decided to check the max size of a substitution variable: 240 characters.

Is there a way within my sqlplus script to read a file's contents into a bind variable? The Oracle documentation seems to hint at this with the GET command, saying that *typically* you'll use this just to load a sql/sqlplus script.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch13.htm#1009882

> file_name[.ext] Represents the file you wish to load (typically a script).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there's a tricky way to do it.
Put something into *props.txt* and run the script:

```
DECLARE
  -- the @@ expression must be in separate line as follows
  file_contents VARCHAR2(32767) := '
@@props.txt
';
BEGIN 
  dbms_output.put_line('===');
  dbms_output.put_line(file_contents);
  dbms_output.put_line('===');
END;
/
```

Note that the file `props.txt` can not contain an "@" or you'll get nested 
SQL*PLUS calls

Comment: Two years later, and I think I still have some uses for this. Give me a few hours to get around to testing this out, and if it checks I'll accept it. Thanks much.

Comment: It doesn't work for a DTD textfile: it is a simple file without "@" characters and I try to create a resource with dbms_xdb.createresource('/public/mydtds/my.dtd', dtd); where dtd is the loaded file as described above. I'll get from dbms_xdb.getContentVarchar2('/public/mydtds/my.dtd') a line like  open=F, temp=T, length=21, chunksize=8132, data=
@@my.dtd

Answer (score 1):

No. `Load` would only store the file contents in Sql*Plus's own sql buffer. You can then `run`, `edit` and `list` the buffer.

A substitution variable is not the right place to load a file into. Use a bind `variable` of type clob for that and load the file contents using `utl_file`. But of course the file has to be located on the server in this case.

**edit**: if the data has to be located on the client, your option would be to load the clob using a pl/sql block and several calls to [dbms_lob.writeappend](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b1425ll8/d_lob.htm#i999705)

Your file would have to look like this (cannot test it ATM):

var l clob;

```
begin
  dbms_lob.createtemporary(l);
  dbms_lob.writeappend(l, 'abcdef...');
  dbms_lob.writeappend(l, 'ijkl...');
end;
/
```

Comment: Thought about utl_file, but then I'd have to get it to the db server's own file system. I don't know that I can realistically get access to that, it's a office politics thing. But the machine running sqlplus, the file's already available to it. I just have to get it into a clob so that I can manipulate it in plsql.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but I'm afraid I don't get it. Declaring a clob is nothing special, but writeappend doesn't seem to be able be able to read from the SQLPlus buffer, which is the only other way I know to get a file's contents into the client side of SQLPlus. Am I being dense?