# Is there any way to read a properties file at client side using sql plus in a .ksh file?

Tags: plsql, sqlplus, ksh

I have a .ksh file from which I connect to Oracle DB at various environments using sqlplus as below

```
sqlplus -s $O_USER/$O_PASS@$O_DATABASE <<-EOF
```

Now, I need to read a properties(.txt) file from sqlplus for dynamically creating a url parameter and this file is located at client side. Is there any way to do this ? I'm ok with reading this via shell script and passing to sqlplus. I'm able to access some string variables in shell script from sqlplus, but is there a way to pass a hash map kind of object from shell script to sql plus ?

A few notes below :

- I can't use UTL_FILE because the properties file should be located at client side only. Because I'm developing a monitoring tool for an application which is connected to the application in various environments and I don't want to or I don't have enough permission to put this properties file in each of those environments. So I want to store this properties file at a single place (client side)
- I can't use TEXT_IO because I'm not using Oracle forms.
- I don't want to put all these properties hard coded in the .ksh file (which will actually work) because there are more than 150 key-value pairs

Comment: Does this option work for you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721274/can-sqlplus-read-the-contents-of-a-file-into-a-variable Read the whole file with this method and then extract info from the content within  PL/SQL.

Comment: This seems like the sort of spatchcocked solution we had to knock up twenty years ago when the world was young and networked computing was still in its infancy. Do you really have no better of monitoring multiple environments than using a `ksh` script reading a properties file???

Comment: @APC This method is being used from long ago and all I'm doing now is some enhancements and I don't want to totally scrape this and start from scratch. Hence thinking of a work around here

Comment: @KaushikNayak  It helped.. Thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome Akhil. So, could you extract data easily from the file contents in  pl/sql ? I'm asking coz you may add  that as an answer urself, which would help others..