# Oracle Sqlplus calling sql script repeatedly in a loop

Tags: oracle, loops, sqlplus

Is it possible to call a script inside a loop via sqlplus?

Suppose we have two files `simple_sample.sql` and `main.sql`:

```
|simple_sample.sql|
   PROMPT HELLO &1

-------------------
|main.sql|
   begin
     for loop_parameter in 1..3 loop
       #magic_call#  @simple_sample.sql  loop_parameter
     end loop;
   end;
   /
```

What can be used instead of `#magic_call#` to obtain this output:

```
sqlplus user/password@schema @main.sql

HELLO 1
HELLO 2
HELLO 3
```

Comment: Won't your own answer  here  be helpful ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30391533/7998591.  Maybe you can run an execute immediate from the contents of the file in a loop?

Comment: @KaushikNayak, that trick can't help me in this case, because I need to execute an sqlplus script, which generally could containt non-SQL instructions. For instance, `PROMPT` will cause a syntax exception in `execute immedite`.

Comment: Ok, So why not a Shell script  or use other programming languages ?  I don't think there's much we could achieve from SQL* plus  or PL/SQL for such user-interactive executions. It is understandable given the fact that  pure database codes are primarily meant to run non-interactively  to extract data from database.

Comment: I agree with @KaushikNayak. You need to write a shell script  to handle the looping (instead of `main.sql`) and pass parameters to that SQL\*Plus script.

Comment: @KaushikNayak,@APC, thank you for valuable advices. Actually, I'm fine with any answer and if in this case it's `no way in sqlplus`, then let it be. It was just interesting to find out if there's a possibility in sqlplus itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**===PL/SQL===**

**1.1**
You can call another script from PL/SQL but **it will be inlined in the code and must be correct PL/SQL snippet**.
So if we modify original scripts

> simple_sample1.sql
>
> ```
> dbms_output.put_line(&1);
> ```
>
> main.sql
>
> ```
> begin
>   for loop_parameter in 1..3 loop
>     @simple_sample1.sql loop_parameter
>   end loop;
> end;
> /
> ```

Then result is following

```
SQL> @main
old   3: dbms_output.put_line(&1);
new   3: dbms_output.put_line(loop_parameter);
1
2
3

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Of course, inlined code may look almost like standalone block if you wrap it with "begin" and "end".

```
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(&1);
end;
```

**1.2** If you want to run arbitrary script from PL/SQL you can run sqlplus from PL/SQL code using DBMS_SCHEDULER... but it's a bit weird, isn't it? I hope it's needless to say that script will be executed in another session created by DBMS_SCHEDULER.

**===SQL===**

**2.** You can inline code into SQL as well, but, again, **query must compile after inlining**.

> hello.sql
>
> ```
> 'HELLO' || ' ' ||
> ```

```
SQL> select
  2  @hello.sql
  3  rownum
  4  from dual
  5  connect by rownum <= 3;
HELLO 1
HELLO 2
HELLO 3

SQL>
SQL> select
  2  #START hello.sql
  3  rownum
  4  from dual
  5  connect by rownum <= 3;
HELLO 1
HELLO 2
HELLO 3
```

**===SPOOL===**

**3.** Finally, you can **generate in a loop what you need, spool it and execute it**.
You can use either SQL or PL/SQL to generate the script. Example below shows SQL approach.

> main_spool.sql
>
> ```
> set echo off;
> set pagesize 0;
>
> spool tmp.sql
> select
> '@simple_sample.sql' || ' ' || rownum x
> from dual
> connect by rownum <= 3;
> spool off
> @tmp.sql
> ```

```
SQL> @main_spool
@simple_sample.sql 1
@simple_sample.sql 2
@simple_sample.sql 3

HELLO 1
HELLO 2
HELLO 3
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I find your answer extremely wholesome.